Is There a Way to Quantify the Complexity of Solutions to Closed-Form Expressions?
Can it be determined just from the structure of a function $f$ how 'complicated' the solution of $f(x)=0$ will be?
Allow me to give some examples:

If $f$ is a quadratic polynomial, then the solution is very easy to express; if it is a quartic polynomial, the solutions require several paragraphs' worth of space to express; any higher degree and the solutions become impossible to express.
When $f(x)=a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)-c$, it's not very hard to solve, but for the seemingly similar case where $f(x) = a\cot(x)+b\tan(x)-c$ I don't know of any way to solve it.
If $f(x)=e^{ax}-b$ or $f(x)=xe^{ax}-b$, then finding the solution requires the definition of a special inverse function. But surely the natural logarithm is 'simpler' than the Lambert W function (perhaps a distiction expressible by comparing the differential equations each one satisfies).

When I say "can it be determined just from the structure" I mean whether in any of these cases one could simply look at expression of the function, say $f(x)=\sin(x)+a\tan(x)$ and determine either 'That's going to be really easy' or 'That's going to be really painful' in some objective manner?

There are some special cases where you realize you know how to do it, and in every other case you assume it's impossible by default, basically. (To find the answer "exactly" or in "closed form," anyway.)

Algebraic simplification: Wikipedia - Simplification
Google: "algebraic simplification" complexity
$\ $
The following are only my own thoughts.
Let's consider an equation $F(x)=c$, with $F$ a function of one variable and $c$ a constant.
The solution of this equation is $x=f(c)$, where $f$ is a function at the place $c$.
We could describe the complexity of $F$ or the complexity of $f$.
Algebraic numbers $x$ can be assigned a degree.
One method to solve an equation is to apply the inverse / partial inverses of the function $F$.
The inverse / a partial inverse of a composition of functions is the composition of the inverses / partial inverses of the member functions of the original composition in opposite order.
Algebraic functions can be assigned a degree.
The elementary functions of Liouville and Ritt are generated by applying finite numbers of $\exp$, $\ln$ and/or unary and/or multiary $\mathbb{C}$-algebraic functions.
All elementary standard functions (the trigonometric functions, the arcus functions, the hyperbolic functions, the area functions) can be presented in this form.
Liouville assigned an order to the elementary functions.
The theorem in [Ritt 1925] that is proven also in [Risch 1979] states that the elementary invertible elementary functions are generated by applying finite numbers of $\exp$, $\ln$ and/or unary $\mathbb{C}$-algebraic functions.
But even if a (partial) inverse of $F$ in closed form doesn't exist, the equation could have solutions in closed form (closed-form numbers, e.g. elementary numbers).
All this information could be used to define a complexity measure.
$\ $
[Ritt 1925] Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90
[Risch 1979] Risch, R. H.: Algebraic Properties of the Elementary Functions of Analysis. Amer. J. Math. 101 (1979) (4) 743-759
